# Sub-sector covers for disks and balls

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, packing-and-covering

Define an open $k$-sector of a disk as the portion between two radii separated
by an angle of $2\pi/k$, but open along the two radii (and closed along the
circle boundary).
Call a set a *sub-$k$-sector* if it is a closed set and a subset of an open $k$-sector.
So an open $2$-sector is a half-disk minus the diameter,
and a sub-$2$-sector is a closed set that fits inside this set.

---

[image: SubSectorCovers]

          

<sup>Left: Coverage by three sub-$2$-sectors.
Right: Four sub-$4$-sectors. Diameters are dotted lines.</sup>

---

It is clear that one can position three sub-$2$-sectors so that they cover a disk (above, left).

> ***Q1***. Is it correct that three sub-semiballs suffice to cover
>   a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$? What is the generalization to $\mathbb{R}^d$?

By a sub-semiball I mean the natural analog: a closed subset of a half-ball
minus its bounding plane.

> ***Q2***. Does it require six sub-$4$-sectors to cover a disk?

I would like to believe that $k{+}1$ sub-$k$-sectors 
suffice—-so little of the quadrant is missing!—but
the drawing above suggests otherwise.

---

**Update**. Here is my attempt to illustrate Douglas Zare's answer to ***Q2***.

---

[image: Sub4Sectors]

---

Comment: How about the center? Perhaps the definitions need minor adjustments?

Comment: @JohnB: The center is not part of an open sector, because the two bounding radii are subtracted from the sector. For the half-disk, the entire diameter is subtracted, including the center.

Comment: Understood, but you say that "It is clear that three sub-2-sectors suffice to cover a disk". However, no sub-2-sector contains the center.

Comment: @JohnB: Ah. I meant that one can position three sub-$2$ sectors so that they cover the disk, as in the drawing. I will try to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On **Q1**. The intersection of sub-semiball with the boundary sphere of the ball cannot contain two opposite points. Thus, bu the Borsuk--Ulam(--Lusternik--Shnirelman) theorem it is impossible to cover this sphere by three such closed sets.

Let me now finish the consideration of **Q2** started by Douglas. For $k\geq 7$, again $k+1$ sub-$k$-sectors suffice!

Take $k-1$ (not sub!) $k$-sectors centered at the center of the disk with very small overlaps. Taking their appropriate sub-$k$-sectors we cover everything except a very small "star" around the center and, roughly speaking, a $(k-\varepsilon)$-sector of a bit larger radius. Now put the $k$th sub-$k$-sector so as to cover the star and most of the $(k-\varepsilon)$-sector, without some part around its boundary *arc*. This arc, together with its boundary, can now be covered by the last sub-$k$-sector.

You may see an example for $k=7$ below. I tried to do my best, but it seems that one needs to be very precise in order to cover the central star; still, it's obviously possible.

[image: Eight sub-7-sectors]

Comment: Edited, so as to address the rest of Q2.

Comment: Good point about sub-semiball; I took the liberty of adopting your terminology.

Comment: OK, I've deleted this part of text.

Comment: After placing the $k-1$ sub-sectors, what remains has angular extent $2\pi/k + \epsilon$. The $k$-th subsector can cover the center star, but will leave a neighborhood of a radius, and a neighborhood of $2\pi/k + \epsilon$ circular arc uncovered. I don't see how this can be covered by one more sub-sector. It seems two are needed...?

Comment: No, if we shift it towards the center, it will leave just a neighborhood of the arc. OK, I'll try to make a corresponding picture by myself (sorry, perhaps with a worse quality...).

Comment: I've added a picture for $k=7$ (surely, of worse quality than yours). I'm not sure that the cental star is covered, but it is clear that it is possible.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your idea---Very nice!! Your drawing is great.

Answer (score 3):

I'll address question $2$: Since the distance between $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ is $\sqrt{2} \gt 1$, you can cover a neighborhood of a radius with a sub-$4$-sector. The remainder of the disk can be broken into four sub-$4$-sectors by dividing it radially. The same idea lets you cover a disk with four sub-$3$-sectors or six sub-$5$-sectors.

When $k \ge 6$, a sub-$k$-sector has diameter less than the radius of the circle. Any sub-$6$-sector containing the center can't contain a point on the boundary. Any sub-$6$-sector contains less than $2\pi/6$ radians of the boundary, so it takes at least seven to cover the boundary. So, at least eight sub-$6$-sectors are needed to cover the disk.

This does not prove that it requires $k+2$ sub-$k$-sectors to cover a disk for $k \gt 6$, but that many suffices by covering a neighborhood of a radius using two sub-$k$-sectors, then dividing the remainder radially.